# Cursor.moveToFirst() returning false

Tags: android, junit, android-cursor, android-contentresolver

I have the following lines of Code : -

```
public class ReminderBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "ReminderBroadcastReceiver";
    public static final String EVENT_REMINDER_ACTION = "android.intent.action.EVENT_REMINDER";
    private Context mcontext;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mcontext = context;
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.i(TAG, "reminder broadcast received ");
        if (action.equals(EVENT_REMINDER_ACTION)) {
            processReminder(intent);
        }

    }

    private void processReminder(Intent intent) {

        Uri uri = intent.getData();

        ContentResolver cr = mcontext.getContentResolver();
        String alarmTime = uri.getLastPathSegment();

        String[] projection = new String[] { CalendarAlerts.EVENT_ID,
                CalendarAlerts.DESCRIPTION, CalendarAlerts.TITLE,
                CalendarAlerts.ALARM_TIME };
        String selection = CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts.ALARM_TIME + "=?";

        Cursor c = cr.query(
                CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts.CONTENT_URI_BY_INSTANCE,
                projection, selection, new String[] { alarmTime }, null);

        ReminderData reminder_data = null;

        if (c != null) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String event_id = c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(CalendarAlerts.EVENT_ID));
                    String event_desc = c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(CalendarAlerts.DESCRIPTION));
                    String event_title = c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(CalendarAlerts.TITLE));
                    long alarm_time = c.getLong(c
                            .getColumnIndex(CalendarAlerts.ALARM_TIME));

                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm",
                            Locale.getDefault());
                    String str_alarm_time = sdf.format(new Date(alarm_time));

                    reminder_data = new ReminderData(event_id,event_desc,event_title,str_alarm_time);

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }

            c.close();
        }

        sendReminder(NotificationType.NOTI_ALARM, 0, reminder_data);

    }
private void sendReminder(int notiType, int arg1, ReminderData data) {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = notiType;
        msg.arg1 = arg1;
        msg.obj = data;

        NotificationQueueManager.getInstance(mcontext).queueNotification(msg);
    }
}
```

I want to do J UNit Testing of the above class, but (c.moveToFirst()) is always returning false.
How can i made it to return true, so that it enters inside the block.

My Test Code is as follows : -

```
    public void testtestonReceive4(){
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarAlerts.EVENT_ID, "1");
            values.put(CalendarAlerts.DESCRIPTION, "2");
            values.put(CalendarAlerts.TITLE, "3");
            values.put(CalendarAlerts.ALARM_TIME, "4");

            ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
    cr.insert(CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts.CONTENT_URI_BY_INSTANCE, values);
    ... 
    ...
    }
```

My Test Code Android Manifest :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.test.app" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am getting error as :-

**java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarProvider2 uri content://com.android.calendar/calendar_alerts/by_instance from pid=18317, uid=10017 requires android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR, or grantUriPermission()**

Comment: when its returning false, it means your query result is an empty set.

Comment: yes, but i want to J Unit Testing of that class. Can, i set it to return true from my Test Code.

Comment: you must have data in your cursor, otherwise it'll return false when calling `moveToFirst`. you should put some data in your `ContentResolver` if you want that method to return `true`

Comment: How can i populate data to it, using my Test Code? so that it returns true.

Comment: use `ContentValues` to insert data into your `ContentResolver`

Comment: i did the same but i got error as cant add data to calendar provider. I changed in android manifest permission also but it didnt work. can u please provide the code to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65900/discussion-between-android-user-and-mohammad-rahchamani).

Answer (score 1):

If your method `c.moveToFirst()` return false is because your cursor is empty but not null (your query was successful).

**EDIT:**
 How to add items to a database:

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarAlerts.DESCRIPTION, "Description");
    values.put(CalendarAlerts.TITLE, "Title");
    values.put(CalendarAlerts.ALERT_TIME, "Your time");

    cr.insert(CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts.CONTENT_URI_BY_INSTANCE, values);
```

Comment: yes its correct. But is there any way to return it to true from my test code so that it enters inside the block.

Comment: Just in case your database has rows and the cursor get elements from that query.

Comment: Can u please provide me the code to populate data so that it returns true?

Comment: I tried the same but its giving above mentioned error. I have added my android manifest also.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you edited the Manifest file as the error message you presented is:

**java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarProvider2 uri content://com.android.calendar/calendar_alerts/by_instance from pid=18317, uid=10017 requires android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR, or grantUriPermission()**

This means the operation is failing because you didn't include:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

in your Manifest file. As I can see it in your post now, I'd say this was the reason for the original error.